# Seting EditText to TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES removes RETURN key

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog, keypad

In an Android app I am using an alert dialog to enter or edit text.
Since I want capitals at the start of a sentence, I use the following code on the EditText view in the dialog:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

This works, but causes the Enter / Return key on the soft keyboard to be replaced with a Done key. I cannot work out how to use `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES` without losing the Return key.

Answer (score 1):

Realized that what I had to do was this:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | editText.getInputType());
```

Now it functions with the **RETURN** key still present, and capitals on the keyboard at the start of a sentence.